# Git rename and create new file with the same old name - git log expected behavior?

Tags: git, rename

When we used VCS that support ID tracking, we had common pattern when we want to extract interface from a given implementation

```
Rename file A.java to AImp.java
Create new file A.java
```

We do it, because want full history of AImp.java (and that merges from old A.java will be merged into AImp.java)

Now we moved to Git, and I want to repeat this pattern:

```
echo "class A {}" > A.java
git add .
git commit -m "new class A"
git mv A.java  AImp.java
git commit -m "rename A->Aimp"
echo "interface A {}" > A.java
git add .
git commit -m "create new interface A"
```

I'm doing the rename and addition in two separated commits so rename detection works.
The current history is like this:

```
e7579fb (HEAD -> master) create new interface A
610a9b3 rename A->Aimp
b94e8bf new class A
```

But (for my opinion) the history of A.java is wrong:

```
git log --oneline --follow A.java

e7579fb (HEAD -> master) create new interface A
610a9b3 rename A->Aimp
b94e8bf new class A
```

I expected to see only:

```
e7579fb (HEAD -> master) create new interface A
```

What do you think ?

(I know that due to rename detection algorithm, I can't expect merge from old A.java into Aimp.java)

Thanks

Boaz

Answer (score 0):

Git's `git log --follow` is a cheesy hack.

What it does is tell Git that, as it works its way back, commit by commit, if it detects that the (single) file you are `git log`-ing has been renamed, it should start looking for commits that affect the old name.

Since you're asking about the *new* file with that name, Git shows you the new commit with the new name.  Then it finds a commit that has a file with the name `A.java`, so it shows you that commit too ... even though the `A.java` here is a *different* `A.java`.

The hack could be improved: if you're running with `--follow` and Git detects a rename *to* the name you're following, Git could just stop there, not showing that commit and not walking that commit's parent(s).  (This is difficult for purely technical reasons, and rather than just improving the hack, it would be better to write a real follower, but that's much harder.)